# Create xtrareport with xml in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to create a xtrareport with xml in asp.net using c#. I created xml and reference to xtrareport. I have also selected data source schmema and data member on xtrareport design and put fields to labels. I have also debugged dataset and it is not empty. But I can't see data on my report page.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"blabla");
SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(@"select * from table",conn);

conn.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(select);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

//ds.WriteXmlSchema(@"C:\dataset.xml");

XtraReport1 rpr = new XtraReport1();
rpr.DataSource = ds;

rpr.PrintingSystem.SetCommandVisibility(PrintingSystemCommand.ClosePreview, DevExpress.XtraPrinting.CommandVisibility.None);
rpr.CreateDocument(true);`
```

Comment: It's unclear how you are using your report in your asp.net page.

Answer (score 1):

personally I create extensions to load and save xml Layout of reports.
I create them with an win application or whatever then save the xml layout:

```
public static void RestoreFromXmlXtraReportLayout(this DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport report, string xmlXtraReportLayout)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlXtraReportLayout))
    {
      string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".repx";
      System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileName, xmlXtraReportLayout);
      report.LoadLayout(fileName);
      System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
    }
}

public static string GetXmlXtraReportLayout(this DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport report)
{
    string tmpFileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".repx";
    report.SaveLayout(tmpFileName);
    string xmlXtraReportLayout = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(tmpFileName);
    System.IO.File.Delete(tmpFileName);
    return xmlXtraReportLayout;
}
```

using Memory Stream ( but it dosn't works fine, some data are lost, but you can try it )

```
public static void RestoreLayoutFromNavigationItem(this DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport report, string xmlXtraReportLayout)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlXtraReportLayout))
    {
        using (Stream xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(xmlXtraReportLayout);
            xDoc.Save(xmlStream);
            xmlStream.Flush();
            xmlStream.Position = 0;
            report.LoadLayoutFromXml(xmlStream);
        }
    }
 }
```

and to load the report I use a web page that contains a ASPxDocumentViewer :

```
<body>
     <form id="formDocumentViewer" runat="server">
    <div>
         <dx:ASPxDocumentViewer ID="mainDocumentViewer" runat="server">
    </dx:ASPxDocumentViewer>
    </div>
</form>
```

in the page Load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  report.DataSource = "your data source";
  string xmlXtraReportLayout = "load it from the saved file";
  report.RestoreFromXmlXtraReportLayout(xmlXtraReportLayout);
  this.mainDocumentViewer.SettingsSplitter.SidePaneVisible = false;
  this.mainDocumentViewer.Report = report;
}
```

but first you have to create your report with the report designer , load it in win application , use GetXmlXtraReportLayout to save the layout into a file.